# Can Lagrange's Theorem for algebraic structure apply here?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups

For a positive integer $n$ let $Φ(n)$ denote the number of elements $r∈\mathbb Z_n$ such that
$\gcd(r,n)=1$. Show $Φ(mn)=Φ(m)Φ(n)$ for all $m, n∈\mathbb N$ such that $\gcd(m,n)=1$.

The only thing I can come up with when seeing this question is that those r's are generators of the ring they are in...

Intuitively, I think I should apply Lagrange's Theorem, but I have no idea how to use it...

Comment: Are we allowed to use the formula for $\Phi$ ? Because it follows rather easily from it.

Comment: What formula? You can try XD

Comment: This is the formula for $\Phi(n)$ where $n=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\cdots p_m^{a_m}$ is the unique prime factorization of $n$ in the ring of integers. $$\Phi(n)=\Phi(p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\cdots p_m^{a_m})=n\left(1-\frac 1{p_1}\right)\left(1-\frac 1{p_2}\right)\cdots \left(1-\frac 1{p_m}\right)$$

Comment: @KatherineWong would give a little of context? There are quite different ways to prove this statements depending on your background knowledge.
What do you know? What theorems can you use?

Comment: @KatherineWong [Euler's product formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_totient_function#Euler.27s_product_formula), for instance. Yet again, your lemma is part of its proof.

Comment: Maybe the most basic method...? Does Lagrange's Theorem apply here?

Comment: Since you seem to be looking for a group-theoretic proof of the statement rather than a number-theoretic proof, see [Euler Phi function is multiplicative if coprime](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Euler-phi_function_is_multiplicative_if_coprime).

Comment: Thank you for your tips! I've worked it out~

Answer (score 1):

A very group theoretic way to prove your claim is outlined in the following:

1. Prove that for $n$ and $m$ co-prime, that is $\gcd(n,m)=1$, you have an isomorphism $\mathbb Z_{nm} \cong \mathbb Z_{n}\times \mathbb Z_{m}$ (where $\times$ denote the direct product of groups).
2. Prove that the generators of $\mathbb Z_n \times \mathbb Z_m$ are exactly ordered pairs $(x,y)$ where $x$ is a generator of $\mathbb Z_n$ and $y$ is a generator of $\mathbb Z_m$.
3. Using your initial observation, namely that $\Phi(n)$ is the number of generators of $\mathbb Z_n$, and the point 1 conclude the claim that $\Phi(nm)=\Phi(n)\Phi(m)$.

Note that in order to prove this points you need to use only properties of  cyclic groups (which usually are proved through *Lagrange's theorem*).

If you need additional hint feel free to ask.